# laravel 5 crude generator for complex database

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-5

I have used some CRUD generator for simple database with laravel. However, im working now on a project with many-to-one relationship and one-to-many
just wanna ask if anyone can recommend me a good CRUD generator with relations for laravel 5.2

thanx in advance

Comment: there are CRUD generator such this one https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator.. but this help for a str8 forward database with no relations, but i want something a bit more advanced

Comment: have you tried infyom?

Answer (score 1):

you may try link below : 
[Laravel Crud with scaffold-interface](https://github.com/amranidev/scaffold-interface)

Comment: i have seen this one.. have u tried it in any project? i want smt that works good if you have quite a big project

Comment: no i do not use this before .... but here relation database also integrated .. i think you use it to make a big project

Answer (score -1):

See if this one helps you. [Laravel crud generator](http://dry-project.lateraljs.org/laravel_gen/)!

Note: i found generated code is fully customization too.

Answer (score -1):

Make a Laravel Application on top of well structed database from this repo. 
https://github.com/digitaldreams/laracrud